# phonegap not updating JS file?

Tags: cordova

I have compiled an app on PhoneGap multiple times(same app), and never had a problem until this afternoon. It seems PhoneGap will not update the js file (app only consists of index.html and mobile.js). If I make changes to the html file and re-build, it shows in the newest APK, but when I update the JS file(even blanked it out as a test), the APK file still has the old JS in it. Am I doing something wrong? And if so what?

Comment: have you tried to clean the project in eclipse?

Comment: Not using Eclipse, using phonegap build (online version). I have now got to the point where it looks like the apk has the updated JS file in it but once installed on the phone it isn't reflected. Very odd, I tried clearing the app cache on the phone as well as uninstalling the app completely on the phone then reinstalling, even with an apparent blank JS file in the build the app still acts as though nothing has changed when installed on the phone.

Comment: can you post the contents of the html file? probably there are some header issues..

Comment: try to add these headers in ur html file `<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">`

Comment: another idea that can help u out is by adding a version number to the js. this is just to make sure that the latest file is loaded. **`<script src="core.js?version=1"></script>`** , so everytime you make a change in the js file, just increment the number..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/noelhanback/runrD/1/

Comment: i dont see the mobile.js being loaded in the code. in any case just use the above way i mentioned **`<script src="mobile.js?version=1"></script>`**

Comment: since the comments were going too long, i added some more input in the answer below.

Comment: Changing the version number fixed it thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html ways of disabling the cache are

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

and add the version number as the query string when loading the js file.

```
<script src="mobile.js?version=1"></script>
```

If these don't work then try disabling the cache of the webview. In the main activity, inside the onCreate method, add either of the lines below.

```
 WebView webview = new WebView(this);
 webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
```

**or**

```
super.appView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
```